# How to define json schema for unknown type in TypeScript using ajv's JSONSchemaType

Tags: typescript, jsonschema, ajv

I am using AJV's JSONSchemaType to create a JSON schema that corresponds to a TypeScript interface with a property that can be of `unknown` type.
However, TypeScript throws errors when trying to assign the schema.

Here's the TypeScript interface and the schema attempts:

```
import { JSONSchemaType } from "ajv";

interface OptionArray {
  options?: {
    title?: string;
    value: unknown;
  }[];
}

const schemaAttempt1: JSONSchemaType<OptionArray> = {
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    options: {
      type: "array",
      items: {
        type: "object",
        properties: {
          title: { type: "string", nullable: true },
          value: {}
        },
        required: ["value"],
        additionalProperties: false 
      },
      nullable: true
    }
  },
  required: [],
  additionalProperties: false
};

const schemaAttempt2: JSONSchemaType<OptionArray> = {
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    options: {
      type: "array",
      items: {
        type: "object",
        properties: {
          title: { type: "string", nullable: true },
          value: true
        },
        required: ["value"],
        additionalProperties: false 
      },
      nullable: true
    }
  },
  required: [],
  additionalProperties: false
};
```

First results in following ts error:

```
The types of 'properties.value' are incompatible between these types.
Type '{}' is not assignable to type '{ $ref: string; } | (UncheckedJSONSchemaType<unknown, false> & { nullable: true; const?: null | undefined; enum?: readonly unknown[] | undefined; default?: unknown; })'.
```

Second, very much like the first, results in similar ts error:

```
The types of 'properties.value' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type '{ $ref: string; } | (UncheckedJSONSchemaType<unknown, false> & { nullable: true; const?: null | undefined; enum?: readonly unknown[] | undefined; default?: unknown; })'.
```

How can I properly define a json schema for a property with type `unknown` in TypeScript using ajv's JSONSchemaType?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgKQMoHkByqDGALAUxAEMAVATzALgF84AzKCEOAImICsA3VgbgCh+wAHYwCUesRzV0YGMAjCAglCjFyifnDgQ5C4QGcA-AC5N27fJgAbAqbgGYUEQHMBFuF2LWArgTM+wgDWwhAA7sLutADaALoCNII4io4O+ETESjBi4DAAjGZoWLiEJBRUADyy8ooqauQAfHAAvOZwMJT+bBAARhwEODCsADRacGBMVLDABAZmCGPaujWG84sWHVRm7KrqI+vawDlzbR6Wndu9-YP7ZxYTuuLys2t3Hla28+0XbI7Owi4RnBhD5rNZiD1Pu0oH5aKM3hYvL4ughEgiaPC3lACABHHzAbEAEzM0VYSL8rFimLuxEJhKO+m8AAVJk8ZidJNYDAQDnDeSCwRCoU4-Os0XztNi8QSCMS4HFMbT6Stmazpi8GN5ufwaAJ+MlDPADOkSFkcnIAEyFDDYE1kTpVPS1XaNFptTZdVhXAZDTEPKbPE4LDzLfRB3ke7bEF23M5HIjhhGR7p9H2xu7+tka4MI9pHKFIZOsP6uIEC8GQroi6gY3keclVmE89HUs5S-FEklk7wUql1uBKhmKVWPdUcrXNs61u7loWN0UecXTuDtmVyhVjQcq6ws0eBsyc7W6pIpI12s1EOQAZmtxTt5QIjpWdXUTVaOaL3pufrV+9OOidVZ-3OLY2Gjep0wseMQETN5P1Tb9+0zMdXlzD4UW+UDiycUthmBUEK2FJsJVzBtUNzbphAIdB6FYEl+zuJBWA9OjfhwgFWBIijtCYljLgQoYuO43jOlY1geggCBbGIYROOXbjEDYPi2BBEAenEOTWwokSqDE8C9iE7SlNE7ZyzkhiLFiCz5KxXEO1lLsG0pLSzi3Rkd1-dkDwnftxUXMVMWXNzhw8vcvM1LkCExVdO3lKydSAA)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used AjvJsonSchemaType but an equivalent schema would be the following

```json
{
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    options: {
      type: "array",
      items: {
        type: "object",
        properties: {
          title: { type: "string", nullable: true },
          value: { 
            "oneOf":[
              { "type": "string"},
              { "type": "object"},
              { "type": "boolean"},
              { "type": "number"},
              { "type": "array"},
              { "type": "null"}
            ]
        },
        required: ["value"],
        additionalProperties: false 
      }
    }
  },
  additionalProperties: false
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried this one as well, but TS keeps complaining:


Type '{ oneOf: { type: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to type '{ type: readonly never[]; } & { [keyword: string]: any; $id?: string | undefined; $ref?: string | undefined; $defs?: Record<string, UncheckedJSONSchemaType<Known, true>> | undefined; definitions?: Record<...> | undefined; } & { ...; }'.
                                  Property 'type' is missing in type '{ oneOf: { type: string; }[]; }' but required in type '{ type: readonly never[]; }'.(2322)


Updated the playground with 3rd attempt, thx for the input.

Comment: utility types JSONSchemaType to convert data type into the schema type to simplify writing schemas, both for JSON Schema (**but without union support**).  This is the reason you can't have multiple types when using these utility types